# Bounding object custom-scapes in webot

Tags: webots

I have made an object like the one in the picture. How to make bounding objects follow their shape?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCnIu.jpg

I learn to make that shape in this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JZvK4GwRAsQ&list=PLt69C9MnPchlWEV5AEhfT2HajlE2SJ55V&index=5&t=0s

Answer (score 1):

In the boundingObject field you can use several shape nodes (including transforms and groups), and it is recommended to use simple basic geometries (sphere, cylinder, box, etc.).

Therefore, you can just put the same geometries that the one you used for the visual part, or even better, use a DEF-USE mechanism (https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/def-and-use).